# Force Windows to rebuild program layout

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, mvvm

Is there anyway to force XAML to completely redraw all of its elements and thereby have all of the data being displayed updated? This is within a MVVM architecture.

Comment: What you need is data aware controls not layout rebuild. that can be achieved by INotifyPropertyChanged event AFAIK.

Comment: I concur, using something like a refresh method is a bad hack to do something which should be done via mechanisms such a [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a MVVM architecture, the View-Model implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and its properties fire the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event. When this event is fired, the View (which is bound to the View-Model using [XAML Binding System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748857.aspx)) receives a notification about the changes in the value of the properties in the View-Model and it refreshes, showing the updated data on screen.

Therefore, if you are using the [MVVM architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), the only thing you need to do in order to reflect changes in the view is updating the properties in your View-Model.

If you have any specific situation in which the binding system is not giving you the desired results, can you please explain in more detail so that it is possible to address your problem better?